# Store temporary data on a DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Can I make my datagridview a container of a temporary data? I don't want to add my datas directly I just wanted it to be stored in a datagridview just like a container. 
is that possible?

I'm thinking of a listbox which will store the user's choices in a combobox. I don't want to add it directly to the database because the datas thre is temporary the user might change/update his choices.

I have a separate button which will add all of them when the user clicks a submit button.

Any examples?? suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the DataGridView to a object list.

Following is my test code(Vs2010 winform):

```
    public class Location
    {
        public int X { set; get; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          List<Location> locations1 = new List<Location>()
            {
                new Location(){X= 100, Y = 200},
                new Location(){X= 300, Y = 400},
                new Location(){X= 600, Y = 500},
                new Location(){X= 700, Y = 800}    
            };

          dataGridView1.DataSource = locations1;
    }
```

**If you want to the change in DataGridView is reflected in datasource. you have to bind to a class member variable instead of local variable.**

Comment: Sir what If I will add the contents of my datagrid into the database? how can I access each row?

Comment: Declare locations1 in my source code as class member variable. the change you made in gridview will reflect into the variable. then you can save it to database. But I think it is better to bind to database directly.

Comment: I don't want to bind it to the database directly sir as the datas are temporary. I will also have a button that will add them into the database. What I'm trying to copy is like a shopping cart you add data in a shopping cart but that is temporary

Comment: I've tried your code sir but it gives me error; can you put example like textbox + button? when the user inputs text and clicks a button it will add in the datagrid?

Comment: My code has no problem in my computer. what error you got? For add data to gridview, you can add data to class member variable first. then  dataGridView1.DataSource = locations1 again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You must first store the data in an object that the datagridview can understand.  For example:

```
using System.Data;
DataTable table = new DataTable(); // <-- temp. in memory table of data
table.Columns.Add("col1");
table.Rows.Add("some data");
table.Rows.Add("some more data");
table.Rows.Add("and more");
myDataGridView.DataSource = table;
myDataGridView.DataBind();
```

The grid will show one column and one row of data.

Comment: sir what If I will add multiple values in the datagridview?

Comment: @rjtubera - I updated my answer to show you how to add more data (use table.Rows.Add();